# How to take a screenshot on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, screenshot

I have flashed Ubuntu Touch on my Motorola Razr GSM (umts_spyder), and would like to take screenshots, but I don't know how. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 23):

## The easy way (tested on BQ Aquaris E4.5 and Nexus 4 (ota9))

Hold **volume up** and **volume down** until you hear the *picture sound* and see the *screenshot flash*.

Your screenshot is now saved in `/home/phablet/Pictures/Screenshots` and you can view them using the *gallery* app.

## Using the commandline (should work on every device)

The `phablet-screenshot` command found in the `phablet-tools` package can take screenshots from an Ubuntu device attached via USB cable.

```
phablet-screenshot foo.png
I: Dumping fb0 ...
2656 KB/s (3932160 bytes in 1.445s)
I: Done
```

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore for the default read-only images.

Comment: Yep.  The `screencap` tool comes from the Android side and works with Surface Flinger.  The answer needs updating with a Mir equivalent.

Comment: here is workaround  at least for now...    
https://bugs.launchpad.net/phablet-tools/+bug/1238839

Comment: Interestingly if you are using a device with multi-boot it somehow only captures the multi-boot screen - some how that is the only thing it will take a picture of when using Mir with it, (using nexus7), also screencap is missing from later versions, so  you can revert to surfaceflinger and copy over screencap from a android install.

Comment: Any update for this on the bq device? I just get `phablet-screenshot screenshot.png
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
` and then nothing..

Answer (score 10):

On the BQ Aquarius Ubuntu Phone you have to press the volume up and down key simultaneously. The screenshot is than saved in the Pictures folder.

Answer (score 2):

I RTFM an it said to just press the volume key. I did - right in the middle and it stored the screen capture in my photo folder.
From the manual:

```
Taking Screenshots
You can take a screenshot at any time by simply pressing and holding down the
volume key. The screenshot will be automatically saved in the Gallery, in the
“Screenshots” folder. If you are accessing the phone via the computer, go to
Pictures > Screenshots.
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this Script: http://people.canonical.com/~j-lallement/touch/mirfbdump

```
chmod +x script.sh
sh ./script.sh
```